# Need help merging two codes together

Tags: python

I am trying to make an autonomous car that has a line sensor and a ultrasonic sensor. The car needs to go forwards if the the line sensor on the left and right is activated

```
if pin16.read_digital == 1 & pin 15.read_digital == 1
   pin2.write_anlog(180)
```

The above code works fine. I have finished the code which integrates the line sensor and the ultrasonic sensor. The finished code is below :

```
from microbit import *
from neopixel import NeoPixel
import time
import machine

def setup():
    display.off()
    np = NeoPixel(pin0, 5)
    np.clear()

    pin4.set_pull(pin4.PULL_UP)
    pin1.set_analog_period(20)
    pin2.set_analog_period(20)

    pin15.set_pull(pin15.PULL_UP)
    pin16.set_pull(pin16.PULL_UP)

def distance():
    pin3.write_digital(0)
    time.sleep_us(2)

    pin3.write_digital(1)

    time.sleep_us(10)
    pin3.write_digital(0)

    output = machine.time_pulse_us(pin4, 1)

    return output * 0.034 / 2

def forward():
    pin2.write_analog(1)

def backward():
    pin2.write_analog(180)

def stop():
    pin2.write_analog(90)

def line():
    if pin15.read_digital() == 1 & pin16.read_digital() == 1:
        return True
else:
    return False

setup()
# pin1.write_analog(90)
sleep(200)
# pin1.write_analog(70) right
# pin1.write_analog(150) right


while True:
    if (distance() > 5) & line():
        forward()
    else:
        stop()
```

This works fine, however when I try to put the left and right in, it does not work. How do I fix this ? The code for left and right is below

```
while True:
if pin15.read_digital() == 1 & pin16.read_digital() == 0:
    pin1.write_analog(180)
    pin2.write_analog(95)
    time.sleep(500)
    pin2.write_analog(90)
elif pin15.read_digital() == 0 & pin16.read_digital() == 1:
    pin1.write_analog(70)
    pin2.write_analog(180)
    time.sleep(500)
    pin2.write_analog(90)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `and` instead of `&`. `&` is *bitwise and*, which binds stronger than `==`, whereas `and` is *logical and*, which binds weaker than `==`.

```
>>> a, b = 0, 1                                                             
>>> a == 0 and b == 1                                                       
True
>>> a == 0 & b == 1                                                         
False
```

The latter example, which corresponds to your `if` statements, is parsed as `a == (0 & 1) == 1`, i.e. `0 == 0 == 1` (and this, by Python comparison chaining, is *not* `(0 == 0) == 1`, which would evaluate to `True`, but `(0 == 0) and (0 == 1)`).

For `a == 1 & b == 1` this is not a problem, but in all other cases, it will behave unexpectedly.

```
>>> cases = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]                               
>>> [a == 0 & b == 0 for a, b in cases] # should be [True, False, False, False]
[True, True, False, False]              # but evaluates as "a == 0 == 0"
>>> [a == 0 & b == 1 for a, b in cases] # should be [False, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, False]            # but evaluates as "a == 0 == 1"
>>> [a == 1 & b == 0 for a, b in cases] # should be [False, False, True, False]
[True, False, False, False]             # but evaluates as "a == b == 0"
>>> [a == 1 & b == 1 for a, b in cases] # should be [False, False, False, True]
[False, False, False, True]             # evaluates as "a == b == 1" ("correct")
```

Comment: Sometimes I get a syntax error with unredable text. Sometimes I get 3 dots on the microbits diplay

Comment: @F.Ahmed How is this related to this half-year-old question? If you have a new problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Arduino nor in the Neopixel library. However, aren't you missing the forward case in your third block of code? Also, it's better to use `and` instead of `&`, because `&` is a bitwise operator and is ranked higher than == in the operator precedence rules, as tobias_k says (you could use parenthesis to work around this if you wanted to, but why would you prefer the bitwise operator?). No need of the == operator, by the way. An integer is automatically evaluated as False in an if statement if it's 0, and True otherwise:

```py
while True:
    read_left, read_right = pin15.read_digital(), pin16.read_digital()
    if read_left and read_right:
        # your code to go forward
    elif read_left and not read_right:
        # your code to turn left
    elif not read_left and read_right:
        # your code to turn right
    else:
        # your code when no line is detected, if you want to handle this case
```

Comment: I still think my answer still applies, though. It doesn't make any difference if it's Micropython since I do not assume any CPython's exclusive feature. Yet, you seem not satisfied, neither by my answer nor tobias_k's. Maybe you should clarify what's exactly wrong about your original code and what is it that our answers do not cover?

Comment: I think you should provide more nuance. Which syntax error do you get? What was it that didn't work the first time (the code didn't run or it ran but it didn't give the expected result)? If you don't give more details, I'm afraid there's nothing else I can suggest. I don't see any syntax error in the skeleton I gave you. Unless, of course, you tried to run it as is, since the if/elif/else blocks are empty and this isn't allowed in Python (that's why you have the `pass` statement).

Comment: Sometimes I get a syntax error with unredable text. Sometimes I get 3 dots on the microbits diplay

Comment: asher atom Sometimes I get a syntax error with unredable text. Sometimes I get 3 dots on the microbits diplay